# How can I sum values in an Excel column based upon a given month?

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

I have two columns of Excel data.  Column A lists dates (like November 15, 2013) and Column B lists dollar amounts (like $125.23).  I'd like to sum all of the values in Column B for the month of November 2013.

Here is what I tried:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$32,$A$1:$A32,">=" & "11/1/13", $A$1:$A$32,"<=" & "11/30/13")
```

The problem with this is that I have to manually type in the month dates.  I'd like to say something like this instead:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$32,$A$1:$A32,"=" & "MONTH="11"", $A$1:$A$32,"=" & "YEAR="2013"")
```

But this doesn't work.  How can I fix this?

*Please Note:* I'm also trying **NOT** to include any additional columns in my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

`=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$32)=11)*(YEAR($A$1:$A$32)=2013)*($B$1:$B$32))`

[image]

Comment: Consider adding an additional factor to specify the year is 2013

Comment: @pnuts: Hey. no worries :) Nah! today is a bad day LOL.